Nested rich (Rich Text - echarts)
I tried using nested rich to align text to the center of a rich: bg section. But, the nesting doesn't work:
formatter: function(params) {
  const nome = params.name;
  const valor = params.value;
        
  return ["{bg| {center|"+nome+"}}",
  "{c|Content}"].join("\n");
}

If I don't nest, the text appears, but not center aligned.
formatter: function(params) {
  const nome = params.name;
  const valor = params.value;
        
  return ["{bg|"+nome+"}",
  "{c|Content}"].join("\n");
}

Complete code:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const myChartUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById("myChart"));

  option = {

    series: [{

      type: "pie",
      radius: ["70%", "55%"],
      padAngle: 5,
      itemStyle: {
        normal: {
          borderRadius: 5
        },
        emphasis: {
          color: "#40bcac"
        }
      },
      label: {
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: 120,
        padding: 2,
        borderColor: "#020202",
        formatter: function(params) {
          const nome = params.name;
          const valor = params.value;

          return ["{bg| " + nome + "}",
            "{c|Content}"
          ].join("\n");
        },
        rich: {
          bg: {
            backgroundColor: "#020202",
            color: "#f2f2f2",
            height: 20,
            width: "100%",
            borderRadius: [3, 3, 0, 0],
            padding: [0, 10, 0, 10]
          },
          center: {
            align: "center"
          },
          c: {
            color: "#020202"
          }
        }
      },
      data: [{
          name: "Value 1",
          value: 78
        },
        {
          name: "Value2",
          value: 22
        }
      ]

    }]

  }

  myChartUse.setOption(option);

})
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="myChart" style="height: 450px; width: 600px;"></div>




Nesting rich text elements doesnt seem to be possible. Doing it like in this official example doesnt quite work either (and I currently dont understand whats different).
Best I could come up with is taking the official approach and adding padding:
Example:
label: {
    ...
    formatter: ['{c1| name }{bg|}', '{c2| Content }'].join('\n'),
    rich: {
        bg: {
            backgroundColor: '#020202',
            height: 20,
            width: '100%',
            borderRadius: [3, 3, 0, 0],
            padding: [0, 10, 0, 10],
            align: 'right'
        },
        c1: {
            padding: [0, 0, 0, 18],
            color: '#f2f2f2',
            align: 'center'
        },
        c2: {
            color: '#020202',
            align: 'center'
        }
    }
},

